# Show that $\Vert T\Vert=\max\limits_{1\leq i\leq n}\vert d_{i}\vert $

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis, operator-theory, linear-transformations

Please give me a hint for the following question.

> The Problem:
>   **(a)**  Let $D\in M_{nn}(\mathbb{R})$ be a diagonal matrix and $T:\mathbb{R}^{n}\to\mathbb{R}^{n}$ be the linear operator associated with $D,$ $Tx=Dx$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}^{n}.$ Show that 
>   $$\Vert T\Vert=\max\limits_{1\leq i\leq n}\vert d_{i}\vert $$
>   where $d_{1}, d_{2}, \cdots, d_{n}$ are the entries on the diagonal of $D$. 
>    For this part of the question I have proved that  $\Vert T\Vert\leq\max\limits_{1\leq i\leq n}\vert d_{i}\vert $

**For this part of the question I have proved that  $\Vert T\Vert\leq\max\limits_{1\leq i\leq n}\vert d_{i}\vert $.**

> **(b)**
>   Suppose $A\in M_{nn}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ is symetric (i.e.,$A^{T}=A$) and $T:\mathbb{R}^{n}\to\mathbb{R}^{n}$ is the linear operator associated with $A$. Show that 
>   $$\Vert T\Vert=\max\{ \vert \lambda\vert; \lambda\; is\; the\; eigenvalue\; of\; A\}. $$

Comment: How do you define $\|T\|$? Is it any matrix norm or do you assume a particular one?

Answer (score 1):

*Hints:* For (a): If you have already proven that the operator norm of $T$ is at most the maximal diagonal entry, now just recognize that there is for sure a vector $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$ which satisfies $|T v|=(max|d_i|) |v|$. This will be a vector of the form $(0,0,0,1,0,0)$ with the $1$ in the component with the largest eigenvalue.

For (b): You know that a symmetric matrix can be diagonalized, so you should try to reduce this to the statement of (a). Write $A = SDS^{-1}$ with $D$ a diagonal matrix.

Comment: For part **(a)** If he takes $x=e_{i}$ he will get $\Vert T\Vert=d_{i}.$ So what will be happened next?
 For part **(b)** he should use this $\Vert SDS^{-1}\Vert=\Vert D\Vert$? Is this true?

Comment: No, no, don't forget that $\| T\|$ is the supremum of all $|Tv|$.

Comment: I could not get the idea. I cant conclude that if $ \sup\limits_{x=e_{i}}\vert Tx\vert=d_{i} $ then $\Vert T\Vert=\max\limits_{i} d_{i}$

Comment: @HamedBaghalGhaffari If $S$ is orthogonal, then $S^{-1}=S^t$ and $\|Sx\|=\|x\|$ for every $x$. So,
$$\|SDS^{-1}x\|^2=\langle SDS^{-1}x,SDS^{-1}x\rangle =\langle DS^{-1}x,DS^{-1}x\rangle=\|Dy\|^2$$
Since $\Bbb R^n=S^{-1}\Bbb R^n$, taking the maximum over $x$, resp. $y$, this indeed show that $\|SDS^{-1}\|=\|D\|$

Comment: @HamedBaghalGhaffari for a), just note that as $\|e_i\|=1$ for all $i$, we have $\max_{i}\|De_i\|\leq \|D\|$.

Answer (score 1):

**A Rayleigh quotient approach:**

Assuming $$\|T\|=\max_{x\neq 0}\frac{\|Tx\|_2}{\|x\|_2},$$
and $T$ is symmetric, then, note that 
$$R(x)=\frac{\|Tx\|_2^2}{\|x\|_2^2}=\frac{\langle Tx,Tx\rangle}{\langle x,x\rangle}=\frac{\langle T^2x,x\rangle}{\langle x,x\rangle}$$
which is nothing else than the [Rayleigh quotient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_quotient) of $T^2$. Hence, we have 
\begin{align*}
\|T\|^2&=\max_{x\neq 0} R(x) \\
&=\max\{|\tilde \lambda|\colon \tilde\lambda \text{ is an eigenvalue of }T^2\}\\
&=\max\{|\lambda|^2\colon \lambda \text{ is an eigenvalue of }T\}\\
&=\max\{|\lambda|\colon \lambda \text{ is an eigenvalue of }T\}^2.
\end{align*}
Of course, any diagonal matrix is symmetric so the first part follows from this argument.

Comment: Note that you can also solve the problem by solving 
$\nabla\frac{\|Tx\|_2}{\|x\|_2}=0$ which is roughly the same argument.